# Dynamic versioning of multiple dependencies in pyproject.toml

Tags: python-poetry

During the same run of a GitLab pipeline two packages are built. Their tag is defined by the environment variable `PROJECT_VARIABLE`. Both are versioned dynamically with Poetry. My current struggle is: one package depends on the other and I would like to indicate its version dynamically too in `pyproject.toml`'s dependencies section.

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-project
version = "0.0.0"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
other-project = "0.0.0"  # <-- line in question

[tool.poetry-dynamic-versioning]
enable = true
format-jinja = "{{ env.get('PROJECT_VERSION') }}"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core==1.7.0", "poetry-dynamic-versioning==1.1.0"]
build-backend = "poetry_dynamic_versioning.backend"
```

The way it is now crashes of course. Th error message is :

```
    Invalid PEP 440 Version: 'None'
```

I tried overriding the pattern so it would catch and edit both but I could not accomplish it.